# Eclipse - creating a class with a custom base

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to create a new class, and I want it to have a certain base, and a certain jar in its build path (Which is craftbukkit.jar). I want to click a button to create a new class. Lets say I named it ThisIsAClass - then it will create a class looking like this (for example):

```
public class ThisIsAClass extends JavaPlugin implements Listener{

    public void onEnable(){

    }
    public void onDisable(){

    }
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args){
        return false;
    }
}
```

And I want it to happen automatically. How can I do that?

Comment: This is automatically done when you create the class through the GUI of Eclipse and add the super class and the interfaces to extend.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza , I tried to create a class named Super, made it as what the top shows, and then created another class (for testing), and instead

Comment: And instead... which problem you faced? I used this after you posted this comment and worked as expected.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I crashed, sorry. Well and instead I faced a class that only extends Super, instead of a class that EXTENDS Super, and does not have onEnable() onDisable() and onCommand(). How can I make a new class having all that?

Comment: Probably those methods are defined in the interface that you haven't provided when creating the class using the right GUI option...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Sorry. Let me clear up the air - The class Super is NOT AN INTERFACE because of a simple reason - I want it to extend a Class and implement a Class, and I can only extend an interface if Super is an interface.

Comment: Again: You have an already created class C and an interface I. In the eclipse GUI for class creation: if you create another class S and set C as its super class, it will generate the code of class S and put the abstract methods in class C to be implemented in class S. If you create S and set I as and interface to implement, it will generate the code of class S with the methods defined in I. If you create S with C as super class and I as interface to implement, it will generate the code of S with abstract methods from C and all the methods from I. What's your specific problem?